# Custom reading CSV files (Keyword accesible / custom structure)

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to do the following:
I downloaded a csv file containing my banking transactions of the last 180 days.
I want to readin this csv file and then do some plots with the data.
For that I setup a program that reads the csv file und makes the data avaible through keywords.
e.g. in the csv file there is a column "Buchungstag".
I replace that with the date keyword etc.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as mpl
import csv

class finanz():

    def __init__(self):

        path = "/home/***/"
        self.dataFileName = path + "test.csv"
        self.data_read = open(self.dataFileName, 'r')
        self._columns = {}
        self._columns[0] = ["date", "Buchungstag", "", "S15"]
        self._columns[1] = ["value", "Umsatz", "Euro", "f8"]
        self._ident = {"Buchungstag":"date", "Umsatz in {0}":"value"}
        self.base = 1205.30
        self._readData()

    def _readData(self):

        r = csv.DictReader(self.data_read, delimiter=';')
        dtype = map(lambda x: (self._columns[x][0],self._columns[x][3]),range(len(self._columns)))
        self.data = np.recarray((2), dtype=dtype)
        desiredKeys = map(lambda x:x, self._ident.iterkeys())

        for i, x in enumerate(r):
            for k in desiredKeys:
                if k == "Umsatz in {0}":
                    v = np.float(x[k].replace(",", "."))+self.base           
                else:               
                    v = x[k]
                self.data[self._ident[k]][i] = v 

    def getAllData(self):
        return self.data.copy()   

a = finanz()
b = a.getAllData()
print type(b)
print type(b['value']),type(b['date'])
```

Sample data

```
"Buchungstag";"Wertstellung (Valuta)";"Vorgang";"Buchungstext";"Umsatz in {0}";
"02.06.2015";"02.06.2015";"Lastschrift/Belast.";"Auftraggeber: abc";"-3,75";
```

My question now is why is type(b['date']) a class 'numpy.core.records.recarray' and type(b['value']) a type 'numpy.ndarray' ??

And my second question would be how to "save" the date in a format that I can use with matplotlib?

The Third and final question is how can I check many rows the csv file has (for the creation of the empty self.data array)

Thx!

Comment: `np.loadtxt` and `np.genfromtxt` collect the `csv` data in a list (of lists) (via list append), and convert that to an array at the end.  They don't need to know the number of rows in the file before hand.  They also readily handle the details of creating a structured array.

Comment: yes that is true. But I do not want to have this format. I want to be able to access the data with keywords and I also do not want to read in all the information provided only selected parts. I want to extend it to like include a certain range of dates etc. I am a little confused why the date is a class und value is a type.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating your array generation without the extra code:

```
In [230]: dt=np.dtype([('date', 'S15'), ('value', '<f8')])
In [231]: data=np.recarray((2,),dtype=dt)

In [232]: type(data['date'])
Out[232]: numpy.core.records.recarray

In [233]: type(data['value'])
Out[233]: numpy.ndarray
```

The fact that one field is returned as `ndarray`, and the other as `recarray` isn't significant.  It's just how the `recarray` class is setup.

Now we mostly use 'structured arrays', created for example with

```
data1=np.empty((2,),dtype=dt)
```

or filled with '0s':

```
data1=np.zeros((2,),dtype=dt)

# array([('', 0.0), ('', 0.0)], 
  dtype=[('date', 'S15'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

With this, both `data1['date']` and `['value']` are `ndarray`.  `recarray` is the old version, and still compatible, but structured arrays are more consistent in their syntax and behavior.  There are lots of SO questions about structured arrays, many produced by `np.genfromtxt` applied to csv files like yours.

I could combine this idea, plus my comment (about list appends):

```
def _readData(self):
    r = csv.DictReader(self.data_read, delimiter=';')
    if self._columns[0][1].endswith('tag'):
        self._columns[0][2] = 'datetime64[D]'
    dtype = map(lambda x: (self._columns[x][0],self._columns[x][3]),range(len(self._columns)))
    desiredKeys = map(lambda x:x, self._ident.iterkeys())
    data = []
    for x in r:
        aline = np.zeros((1,), dtype=dtype)
        for k in desiredKeys:
            if k == "Umsatz in {0}":
                v = np.float(x[k].replace(",", "."))+self.base
            else:
                v = x[k]
                v1 = v.split('.')
                if len(v1)==3:  # convert date to yyyyy-mm-dd format
                     v = '%s-%s-%s'%(v1[2],v1[1],v1[0])
            aline[self._ident[k]] = v
        data.append(aline)
    self.data = np.concatenate(data)
```

producing a `b` like:

```
array([(datetime.date(2015, 6, 2), 1201.55),
       (datetime.date(2015, 6, 2), 1201.55),
       (datetime.date(2015, 6, 2), 1201.55)], 
       dtype=[('date', '<M8[D]'), ('value', '<f8')])
```

I believe `genfromtxt` collects each row as a tuple, and creates the array at the end.   The docs for structured arrays shows that they can be constructed from

```
np.array([(item1, item2), (item3, item4),...], dtype=dtype)
```

I chose to construct an array for each line, and concatenate them at the end  because that required fewer changes to your code.

I also changed that function so it converts the 'tag' column to `np.datetime64` dtype.  There are a number of SO questions about using that dtype.  I believe it can used in `matplotlib`, though I don't have experience with that.

Comment: Thx alot I will change the code to use structured arrays. What mostly confused me was that one was a class and one was a type. I try to avoid appends mostly because its slows down the code down the line (maybe I am wrong here but thats what I remeber from last time I coded in python). Sure for this case it does not matter but I was just curious if it would be possible to do it without an append. I got the matplotlib working with ax.set_xticklabels(self.data['date'],rotation=90) and ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, len(b['date']), 1)) works like a charm.

Comment: `recarray` and `ndtype` are both classes.  Append to an array is slow, append to a list not so much.  If you know how many data rows there are, then preallocation of the array works.  But with a text file you only know the number of lines by reading the whole file.